# How can I hide the URL bar in a PWA?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm building a PWA and it follows all rules, it has even an HTTPS URL:

https://toastmasterstimer.tk

But the URL bar is still appearing:

[image: preview]

The App is installable since it fulfills all rules and I have tested it in Chrome from my Android Phone:

[image: preview 2]

This is my **Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tk.supernovaic.tmtimer.go"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                hostName: "toastmasterstimer.tk",
                defaultUrl: "https://toastmasterstimer.tk",
                launcherName: "Toastmasters Timer - Go",
                assetStatements: '[{ "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"], ' +
                        '"target": {"namespace": "web", "site": "https://toastmasterstimer.tk"}}]'
        ]

        resValue "color", "colorPrimary", "#272838"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs:e849e45c90'
}
```

And this is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.placeholder">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="${launcherName}"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TwaSplash">

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:value="${assetStatements}" />

        <activity android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity"
            android:label="${launcherName}">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="${defaultUrl}" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="${hostName}"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is the **style.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.TwaSplash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I followed this **tutorial**:

[Trusted Web Activity - PWA to Play Store Guide](https://fireship.io/lessons/pwa-to-play-store/)

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to fix this in your manifest file (start_url" : "https://fanmixco.github.io/toastmasters-timer-material-design/)  Looks like that is not right. if your app is at the root of your domain

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, I forgot it!

Answer (score 1):

The domain `toastmasterstimer.tk` seems to be missing the Digital Asset Links file, necessary to validate ownership and enable fullscreen.

The file needs to be available at `https://toastmasterstimer.tk/.well-known/assetlinks.json`.

You can use the [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) to generate the `assetlinks.json` file.

This [section](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa#link-site-to-app) of the documentation provides more information, including how to extract the SHA-256 fingerprint from your signing key.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your APK, you will sign the app with a key-store.

Once you create a key-store, you will need to get a `sha256 fingerprint`.

To get the sha256 you will need to run:

`keytool -list -v -keystore /keystore-location/pwa-keystore.ks`

Then, make sure the following route available on your web app, containing your sha256 fingerprint generated above.

www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

```
    {
      "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "scapeq",
        "package_name": "org.electrobooth.twa.scapeq",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["sha256_FINGER_PRINT_GOES_HERE"]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the sha256 fingerprint you entered in your web/.well-known/assetlinks.json
is the same as the one entered in google play console? 
(On "Release Management" / "App signing" "App signing certificate")

```
    [{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target" : { "namespace": "android_app", "package_name": "package.name",
                 "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["**this:one**"] }
  }]
```

[image: google play console screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your manifest before u port to android:

```
     "display": "standalone"
```